# Upload video on vimeo using vimeo video upload api

Tags: php, video, upload, vimeo

http://vimeo.com/oauth/confirmed

> Authorization successful
> You have successully authorized “My App” to access your account.
> To start using “My App”, go back to the application and enter the following
> code
>
> ```
> toys-ve14o
> ```

Where i can add this code?

Comment: Thats the user authentication key, which you'll need your app to handshake with Vimeo before you upload. See this http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced#oauth and its generally not a good idea to post your private keys here.

Comment: @Jingesh What is the actual question your asking?